# Discrepancy between location reported by Google Analytics and that of IP address

Tags: google-analytics, ip, analytics, ip-address, ip-geolocation

I've modified my Google Analytics to show visitor IP addresses, and I recently noticed one user that is reporting from a specific city - however, when I lookup the IP address, it says it's based in a city 250 miles away.

Why is this, and which location is more accurate (if at all)?

Answer (score 1):

Where did you lookup the IP address ? The databases of IP lookup service may be out of date. There are lots of companies that provide both database & lookup API and at times there can be discrepancy between the locations. IP addresses get re-assigned so the database has to be updated regularly.

Comment: It seems to be accurate for everything else though.

Comment: As I wrote above, its completely possible to have a discrepancy between various databases for certain address ranges.